# Send a message, not forward, when applying rules in Office365

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365

Using Outlook 365 (Version 2304) on Windows 10. Under `Rules and Alerts` it is possible to define a rule to `forward it to people of public group`. The problem is that the actual message (and its' content) are sent, which is not what I need.

I'd like to send a custom message, a kind of notification, something along the lines of:

```
Subject: New message received from X
Body: Log into Outlook to read, or contact Y to find out more.
```

In other words, the actual content of the email should NOT be forwarded. I don't want to forward the whole email for (a) privacy and (b) some messages are large and should really only be viewed (and not forwarded around).

Is this possible in Outlook 365?

Comment: Generally rules do not send custom messages, so I do not think Outlook will do what you want. You would need to forward manually and cut out content you do not want. I do this routinely.

Comment: Agree with John.